# App engine cron job restarts on failures

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a Cron job that restart automatically if it fails with 503 error.
This is not the expected behavior. It consumes all my quotas.

Is there any way to stop my crawler if it returns with an internal server error like 50x?

[image: See events log]

I incur in a NullPointerException and the cron jobs restart automatically:

[image]

This is my cron.yaml file:

```
cron:

- description: "Daily crawler job"
  url: /_ah/api/followFunAdmin/v1/cron/crawler
  schedule: every 24 hours
```

Comment: can you please post the configuration for your cron jobs? The cron.xml file?

Comment: @MichaelMeyer updated question with cron conf

Comment: the url looks a little bit strange. did you try to use url: /cron/crawler instead of url: /_api .... ?

Comment: Can you post your handler code as well? Is it possible that the crawler itself launches subsequent additional requests to the same URL?

Comment: Mmh no, the cron job is a bit complex but I'm sure, it doesn't call itself. :(